# Ruby OptionParser does not set a parameter

Tags: ruby

This is my parser:

```
options = { frames: 12, showcurrent: false}
optparse = OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.banner = "Usage: example.rb [options]"
  opts.on("-f", "--frames", "Only tickets of the last x time frames (default: 12)", Integer) { |v| options[:frames] = v }
  opts.on("-c", "--show_current", "Show current (false (default) ot true)") { |v| options[:showcurrent] = v }
  opts.on("-t", "--time", "Type of the report (day, week (default), month, quarter, year)", String) { |v| options[:time] = v }
  opts.on("-w", "--year_week YEAR-WEEK", "wrYYWW (wr1707)", String) { |v| options[:yw] = v }
end
optparse.parse!
puts options
```

after I run the code with `ruby main.rb -t 'w' -w 'wr1707'` the options are following:

```
{:frames=>12, :showcurrent=>false, :time=>nil, :yw=>"wr1707"}
```

For some reason options[:time] is not set and I do not understand why. Is there maybe some problem with conversions, that I am not allowed to use -t as a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When expecting arguments, you should tell `OptionParser` which argument and if it's optional or obligatory, see [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html#method-i-make_switch):

```
"--switch=MANDATORY" or "--switch MANDATORY"
"--switch[=OPTIONAL]"
"--switch"
```

So in your case, for the `time` option, description should be like this:

```
opts.on("-t", "--time TIME", "Type of the report (day, week (default), month, quarter, year)", String) { |v| options[:time] = v }
```

or like this, if you want to do it optional:

```
opts.on("-t", "--time [TIME]", "Type of the report (day, week (default), month, quarter, year)", String) { |v| options[:time] = v }
```